# Advice software to create flow-charts of programm

Tags: programming-languages, modeling, flowchart

Can you advice me software to create flow-charts for program logic.
My problem is that I've created complicated algorithm with lots of if...else and I need to create flow-chart for all of that to avoid mistakes.
The example of what I want to have is [this http://www.fceditor.ru/files/pic1.gif](http://www.fceditor.ru/files/pic1.gif)
But I don't want it to create flow-chart from source code. I want to create it myself
or [image: this one]
<sub>(source: [analog.com](http://www.analog.com/library/analogdialogue/archives/43-07/AD43_07_FIG-06.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic answer to this is [Microsoft Visio](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/), but there also [a number of free / open source options](http://www.osalt.com/visio).  The best of these is probably [Dia](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/a-free-open-source-alternative-to-microsoft-visio/).

Comment: This is the most obvious option but disadvantages are: it won't re-size your flowchart automatically when you create large structure dipper and dipper

Comment: OK. I tried to use MS Visio with success. It was the best of what I've seen today. Suitable for building various types of charts quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

You might tske a look at GraphViz if you are keen to draw the flowcharts yourself.

Comment: This one is too complicated. I need some kind of basic algorithm flowchart like on screenshow I provided

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your flowchart manually/prospectively, before you code, as opposed to automatically/retrospectively, after you code, it is hard to beat a plain old-fashioned mechanical pencil, Faber-Castell (R) Magic Rub (R) eraser, and a big sheet of paper.  I've had to use a drafting table and H-size paper a couple of times in my life.  An IBM flowchart template (if you can find one HEH HEH HEH) helps.

One of the things this exercise teaches you is not to paint yourself into that particular corner ever again, as in don't make your logic that complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visio or Visual Paradigm Community Edition.